# Some $\LaTeX$ is going out of date?

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

Some days ago I edited an answer by David Mitra because the command `\cases{ }` seemed to be outdated, and changed it with the command `\begin{cases} \end{cases}`

The same seems to have happened [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn) with Arturo's answer.

The purpose of this is twofold:

1. Find out what is going on with this.
2. Call on anyone who is willing to spot this failures and correct them.

Comment: Err... $f(x) = \cases{1&if $x=0$\\2&otherwise}$ (Made by `$f(x) = \cases{1&if $x=0$\\2&otherwise}$`.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin Well, maybe that is not it, and it is something else. See Arturo's answer.

Comment: The [MathJax release notes](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/whats-new-2.0.html) state that the second column of `\cases` has been tweaked to automatically use `\text`; does this explain the problem you see?

Comment: @Lord_Farin That is probably it.

Comment: The referenced answer by Arturo does not presently use the `\cases` command. I wasn't able to find a revision of it that did.

Comment: Some old posts seem to use kludges discussed e.g. in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1119/ or http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/544/ or http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/813/ in order to work around excaping issues with markdown and MathJax. It appears that tricks like `\\{` or `\\\ ` were necessary to display curly braces or to get line breaks in matrices or aligned math environments. It seems that the newer version of the software now breaks this old code.